# my variable is not echoing <br> tag when it gets to the mail function

Tags: php, forms

I am creating my own contact form and sending all the inputs through variable to the mail function

But there is one error in it......my code is like this in the below...

```
$from = $_POST["from"];
 // sender

$name = $_POST["name"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

// message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$mytour = $_POST["select1"];
$howmany = $_POST["select2"];
$arrival = $_POST["arrival"];
$departure = $_POST["departure"];
$accommodation = $_POST["select3"];
$company = $_POST["company"];

// send mail
$messagecontent = "Name:$name , " . "Email:$from ," . "Nature of Enquiry:$subject ," . "Message:$message ," . "Phone No:$phone, " . "My Tour Wish List: $mytour, " . "How many days do you have available:$howmany, " . "Arrival Date:$arrival ," . "Departure Date:$departure ," . "My Preferred Accommodation:$accommodation, " . "Company Name:$company ,";

// $messagewithbreak=str_replace(',',', <br/>;',$messagecontent); // code replaces all your commas with , and a <br> tag

mail("abc@gmail.com", " Contact form Filled", "$messagewithbreak", "From: $from\n");
echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
}
```

But when I receive it in the my email...there is not break tag `<br>` tag...and it receives as....

```
Name: , Email:abc@gmail.com ,Nature of Enquiry:none ,Message:none ,Phone No:none,My Tour Wish List: Heritage Tour of Kells,How many days do you have available:Half a Day, Arrival Date:2014-09-10 ,Departure Date:2014-09-10 ,My Preferred Accommodation:Hostel,Company Name:none
```

But I want it to view proper in the email.... as that is not the professional way... to see the email moreover it is difficult to read the email like this.....

what should I do please help me on it....

I will really appreciate your help.

Please answer my question nothing is helping me out here.I have tried..the methods given to me by jenz and rakesh but still the form when receive in the email shows as the paragraph without line breaks....it is getting frustrating

Answer (score 1):

Properly add formatting to your message. Any HTML tags placed inside double quotes will be converted to the tag when you echo it. So you just need to add `<br>` in proper places inside the message content. Also all PHP variables inside double quotes will get replaced by its value. So no need of appending each string with double quotes.

```
$messagecontent="Name:$name <br> Email:$from <br>Nature of Enquiry:$subject 
<br>Message:$message<br>Phone No:$phone<br>
My Tour Wish List: $mytour<br>How many days do you have available:$howmany<br> Arrival Date:$arrival <br> Departure Date:$departure <br> My Preferred 
Accommodation:$accommodation<br>Company Name:$company ";
```

To send HTML email you have to add headers which is optional by default where we pass Content-Type type declaration telling mail services that parse this email as HTML.

```
  $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

and pass `$headers` in `mail()` like,

```
mail("abc@gmail.com", " Contact form Filled", $messagecontent, $headers);
```

Comment: I reallly appreciate your help...but still it is showing the same.

Comment: can i add two emails in email section like this 'abc@gmail.com,abc2@gmail.com'

Comment: well, Jenz thanks for your help and i tried you $headers code also but still it is not working...i dont know why....Maybe gmail does not see the <br> tag ....It may receive well to other email clients.Can that be a reason >....I dont know why it is happening....I dont have much practical experience in php

Answer (score 1):

why you concat message string again and again. Also remove double quotes from variables in mail()

```
$messagecontent="Name:$name , Email:$from , Nature of Enquiry:$subject , Message:$message , Phone No:$phone, My Tour Wish List: $mytour, How many days do you have available:$howmany, Arrival Date:$arrival , Departure Date:$departure , My Preferred Accommodation:$accommodation, Company Name:$company ,";
$messagewithbreak=str_replace(',',',<br>',$messagecontent);
mail("abc@gmail.com"," Contact form Filled", $messagewithbreak, $from);
```

Comment: Still showing the same ...way..I have tried all the methods have been told to me on this page...but nonthing is happening...still shows the form as paragraph with line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use HTML in a plain text email.  If all you want to do is have line breaks, then use \n instead of the br tag.

If you want to use HTML in an email you must add a content-type header. See the PHP mail docs for an example.

Comment: I dont know how to use content-type header.

Comment: You don't need to set the header for plain text emails, and you can add line breaks with the newline character in plain text emails. If you are still interested in HTML emails, read the php mail() docs. There are examples in the docs for sending all kinds of emails. HTML, with attachments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
// send mail
$messagecontent = "Name:$name \n ";
$messagecontent.= "Email:$from \n";
$messagecontent.= "Nature of Enquiry:$subject \n";
............
...............
```

Set all the variables like that.